# Known Limitations of Picture Library

Tags: 2010, picture-library

Are there any known limitations of Picture Library in respect to:

1. Maximum number of items in the Library
2. File size of individual files
3. File types of individual files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen anything published as such.  The size and type would be limited by the web application blocked file types and the maximum upload size.  The maximum number of files would echo the same principles of a large document libary, limit the number of items per view to avoid performance degradation and/or make use of folders.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary < This link has the info. Thx Eric

Comment: Should have figured there was something on TechNet, I don't troll that KB nearly as much as I should it seems.